# Trying to compare every number out of this list with the 1 infront of it and the 1 after it

Tags: python, string, list, numbers, compare

I'm trying to compare every number out of this list with the 1 infront of it and the 1 after it.
For example: I got a list participants = ["A:1", "B:6", "C:5", "D:4", "E:7", "F:3", "G:10", "H:2"]
Now I wanna compare the number of B:6 to A:1 and C:5, but I have no idea how since that A,B and C are still in the way and I need to keep them for later.

Comment: Migth be worthwhile to use a `dict`, or a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if maintaining the order is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split`, `int` and `zip`. 
Let's name your list `l`:

```
for previous, current, next in zip(l[:-2], l[1:-1],l[2:]):
    nums = [int(x.split(':')[1]) for x in [previous, current, next]] 
    # now do your comparison...
```

Comment: Thank you :)
This helped allot!

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), if you need to maintain order, but want to properly split the keys and values. The advantage is that you have a proper key-value store of your values, but you also still maintain the order the values were added, like with a `list`.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
participants = ["A:1", "B:6", "C:5", "D:4", "E:7", "F:3", "G:10", "H:2"]
d = OrderedDict()
for p in participants:
    letter, number = p.split(':')
    d.update({letter:int(number)})
```

Using `d.keys()` you can access the keys, using `d.values()` you can access the values. So, for example, to print the difference of all numbers to the previous one, do something like this (python 2 code):

```
from __future__ import print_function # necessary for print() in py2.*
for prev, next in zip(d.keys()[:-1], d.keys()[1:]):
    print(next, "-", prev, "=", d[next] - d[prev])
```